# ArgoCD doesn't delete CRD when prune flag is set

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

With ArgoCD, when the prune flag is set in the application. On removal of the Custom resources from the source repo the argocd doesn't delete it from the target cluster.

All the other resources get deleted expect the custom resource so can anyone please suggest a solution or have you faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, faced this issue, here is what you need to do:

Locate CRD in question

```
kubectl get customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io -A
```

Patch it

```
kubectl patch customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io stuck-crd.io -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Delete

```
kubectl delete customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io stuck-crd.io
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Gitlink by KlavsKlavsen](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/6078) this is a known issue and this is in enhancement mode. Seems to be you already using the prune flag but can you try this once   “ --prune-non-existent-resources” flag when running the argocd sync command. This flag will delete any resources in the target cluster that do not exist in the source repository .